# WS02 BAM - Analytics Framework

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

In Cassandra Cluster EVENT_KS Key Space , I have a bookTicket1 (stream) and it has columns 
payload_provider,payload_totalNoTickets. When I tried to a new Analytics script as below  ,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BusTicketTable 
(provider STRING, totalNoTickets STRING,  version STRING) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
"cassandra.host" = "127.0.0.1" , 
"cassandra.port" = "9160" , 
"cassandra.ks.name" = "EVENT_KS" , 
"cassandra.ks.username" = "admin" , 
"cassandra.ks.password" = "admin" , 
"cassandra.cf.name" = "bookTicket1" , 
"cassandra.columns.mapping" = ":payload_provider,payload_totalNoTickets, Version" );
```

It returns the error:

> ERROR: Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this line,

```
"cassandra.columns.mapping" = ":payload_provider,payload_totalNoTickets, Version"
```

There the key is not set in Cassandra. I am not sure but I think you may have to set the key as well because the row key is mandatory for Cassandra column family.

e.g.:
    "cassandra.columns.mapping" = ":key, payload_provider,payload_totalNoTickets, Version"

You may need to set a unique field as the key.